# Analytic function from $L^{p}$ of the complement of a unit disk

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $1\leq p<\infty$. Is there any nonzero function $f$ that is analytic on $\mathbb{C}\backslash\mathbb{D}$ and from $L^{p}\left(\mathbb{C}\backslash \mathbb{D}\right)$? Here $\mathbb{D}$ is a closed unit disk in $\mathbb{C}$, i.e. a set of all $z\in\mathbb{C}$ such that $\vert z\vert\leq 1$.

Comment: How about $1/z^2$ ?

Comment: @Glougloubarbaki Take $1/z^3$ to have it in $L^1 \cap L^\infty$.

Comment: @Glougloubarbaki By the way, what about making that an answer?

Comment: Good answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to Daniel for correcting me in the comments. Consider $f(z)=1/z^3$ : $f$ is obviously holomorphic outside the origin. It is integrable on $\mathbb{C} \backslash \mathbb{D}$, a fact that can be seen using polar coordinates. Thus it is a fortiori in $L^p(\mathbb{C} \backslash \mathbb{D})$ for all $1<p<\infty$.

Remark : more generally, the space of holomorphic and $L^p$ functions on an open set of $\mathbb{C}$ (or more generally a Riemann surface) is called the Bergman space, usually denoted $A_p(U)$, and it is never trivial.

Comment: "Correcting" is the wrong word. Your $1/z^2$ is in $L^p(\mathbb{C}\setminus\mathbb{D})$ for $1 < p \leqslant \infty$. I just suggested a minor modification to get something that is also in $L^1$.

Comment: I think $A_{p}\left(\mathbb{C}\right)$ only contains zero function. I wanted to see are there Bergman nontrivial functions on $\mathbb{C}\backslash\mathbb{D}$. Thank you both of you.